# How to script a test for Perforce connectivity across multiple servers

Tags: shell, ssh, perforce

I'm trying to automate a few checks I need to do across a bunch of servers as they're built. I need to ssh to the servers, check the free space, and check if there is p4 connectivity. I output the results to a log and it's later parsed. My code below works, but if p4 connectivity fails, I don't get any real output, it just kills the ssh and moves onto the next server. Is there a way to set a time limit only on the piece that checks for p4 connectivity, and if that limit is reached I can output "p4 error" to the log? So, it would be like I have a timer only on this piece of the commands ran in the ssh:

```
echo \\\"<CONN>\\\" export P4PORT=${p4port}; /usr/local/bin/p4 info | grep Server | grep address; \\\"</CONN>\\\";"
```

Here is an example of what I currently have:

```
servers="server1 server2 server3"
dated=`date +%Y%m%d`
log="p4connectivity_${dated}.txt"

echo "Script starting at `date` > $log
for server in $servers
do
        echo $server >> $log
        ssh -o ConnectTimeout=60 ${user}@${server}.${fqdn} "echo \\\"<BEGIN>\\\"; date -u +%m%d%Y_%H%M%S_%Z; echo \\\"</BEGIN>\\\";  echo \\\"<FREE_SPACE>\\\"; df -k | grep app; echo \\\"</FREE_SPACE>\\\"; echo \\\"<CONN>\\\" export P4PORT=${p4port}; /usr/local/bin/p4 info | grep Server | grep address; \\\"</CONN>\\\";" >> $log 2>&1
done

echo "Script is finished"
```

I'm thinking I could do something like:

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `p4 ping` command.  I'm not sure, but it might have different error characteristics than `p4 info`.

Better yet, why don't you just issue `p4 info` from the local machine, rather than doing it over ssh?